# WCF with Mono - Service client works in windows but not in CentOS

Tags: wcf, mono

I created a simple service just to try WCF in Cent OS. 
I created the service client with MonoDevelop in Windows, and it worked fine. When I try to run it on CentOs (using the same configuration file), it throws an error constructing the client, I traced it here:

```
                ExtensionElementCollection extensions = ((ExtensionsSection) EvaluationContext.GetSection ("system.serviceModel/extensions")).BindingExtensions;
                for (int i = 0; i < extensions.Count; i++) {
                    ExtensionElement extension = extensions [i];
                    _properties.Add (new ConfigurationProperty (extension.Name, Type.GetType (extension.Type), null, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None));
                }
```

In System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BindingsSection

the error is an argumentNullException in ConfigurationProperty constructor, type is null. So Type.GetType from EvaluationContext.GetSection ("system.serviceModel/extensions") is failing.
I dont have the extensions section in the config file, and this same Client works perfectly in Windows.
Any hints.

Here is my config file:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPairArithmeticService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://theIp/AlertService/Services/PairArithmeticService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPairArithmeticService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IPairArithmeticService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPairArithmeticService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Mono version 2.11.4, I used gacutil -l System.ServiceModel and I have both System.ServiceModel.dll v3.0 and v4.0. I guess its trying to GetType of BasicHttpBinding and for some reason it fails.

Comment: try removing old versions from the gac so you have only one ServiceModel.dll

Comment: Good try, but it didn't work.

Comment: Then I would try mono master branch (WCF still receives fixes nowadays, i.e.: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/ea570f3a7676871dd565a706e28f99089e660dbc ). If it still fails with that, report a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: That did it, I installed mono 3.0.0 and its working fine. Thanks